# Can't run my Springboot/Oracle application. Port problems

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to run my Springboot application. I need to connect to my Oracle database but I'm getting an error related to the port that it is installed on. It's an Oracle 11g Express Edition installation. Should I then change the port of my Oracle installation and if so, how?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-02-06 13:58:27.402  INFO 6432 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@45a48c09: startup date [Mon Feb 06 13:58:15 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-06 13:58:27.404  INFO 6432 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-02-06 13:58:27.406  INFO 6432 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-02-06 13:58:27.406  INFO 6432 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: drop table tmt.users cascade constraints
2017-02-06 13:58:27.516 ERROR 6432 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000478: Unsuccessful: drop table tmt.users cascade constraints
Hibernate: drop sequence tmt.id_seq
2017-02-06 13:58:27.528 ERROR 6432 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000478: Unsuccessful: drop sequence tmt.id_seq
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1235)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1224)
    at cz.nnit.TmtApplication.main(TmtApplication.java:14)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.689 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-06T13:58:27+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 56M/482M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) on project tmt: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you read the exception? You are starting tomcat on the default port 8080 apparently something is already listening on port 8080.

Comment: Yeah that's what my question's title and summary says... I'm not sure how to force change the port of my Oracle db.

Comment: Again have you READ the stack trace and error... Judging from your comment you haven't... It isn't complaining about your oracle db it is complaining about your tomcat startup.... I highly doubt that your OracleDB is running on port 8080....

Comment: Sorry I should have provided proof. I'll update. My OracleDB is in fact running on 8080.

Comment: Please go through  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7268

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it's not possible to have both Oracle and Tomcat running on the same port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution to your Question**
 **Two Possible ways** 
 1. Please change your Oracle Port to some other Port like 8081 or 9080. 
 2. Change the Tomcat Port in Spring-Boot application properties file.
 3. Add the below following lines in src/main/resources/**application.properties**

```
server.port=8081.
```

Comment: I was about to post this. I moved my Tomcat port to 80801 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because i closed Eclipse suddenly with my springboot app still running and the JAVA process was still running in background. That's why the port was in use in my case.